# VS2010 DTE Addin: project inside solution folder is not "Project"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in, projects-and-solutions

I have a small vs addin which looks for projects inside a solution and does a few stuff with it. I collect the projects like this:

```
Application.DTE.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>();
```

However, as soon as I introduced a solution folder and placed a project inside it, suddenly that project was nowhere to be found. So, I've tried

```
 private IEnumerable<Project> getProjectsRecursive(IEnumerable<Project> iEnumerable)
 {
      foreach (var item in iEnumerable)
      {
          yield return item;
          foreach (var child in getProjectsRecursive(item.ProjectItems.OfType<Project>()))
          {
              yield return child;
          }
      }
 }
public IEnumerable<Project> EveryProject { get { return getProjectsRecursive(Application.DTE.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>()); } }
```

still the project is not there. So I've checked manually, calling `item is Project` on a

- project directly inside the solution is **TRUE**
- solution folder directly inside the solution is **TRUE** (small wtf)
- project inside a solution folder (I've found it in `folder.ProjectItems`) is **FALSE** !!!!! (and of course explicit casting throws an error)

**What the hell?**
Without casting it to `Project`, I cannot call `FullName`, `Properties()` and many other things on it, even if I cast to *dynamic*. Please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is here : http://www.wwwlicious.com/2011/03/29/envdte-getting-all-projects-html/

Just few changes :

```
if (project.Kind == EnvDTE.Constants.vsProjectKindSolutionItems)
```