# What is "Miscellaneous Files" inside DTE VS2010 Solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in, projects-and-solutions

Following up on my previous question:
[VS2010 DTE Addin: project inside solution folder is not "Project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410911/vs2010-dte-addin-project-inside-solution-folder-is-not-project)
I successfully found all my projects in the solution. However, the code also founds an extra item named "Miscellaneous Files". It's `Kind` is different to the solution folders and the projects as well, but there are no more constant kinds fixed in the `ProjectKinds` class (for that matter there isn't one for "Projects" either...)

- **What is this item?**
- **Should I be concerned about this?**
- **Why are there no more constants in** `ProjectKinds`**?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The "Miscellaneous Files" node is used to contain open files that are not associated with the current project contents within the solution. For example, open a solution from C:\Foo\MySolution\ then open a 'loose' file from C:\SomeOtherPath\MyFile.cs, you'll notice that it stored under "Miscellaneous files". This information is persisted if the solution is saved whilst these files are open, it is removed from "Miscellaneous files" once the solution is closed.

  If you wish to "see" the contents of "Miscellaneous Files" in Solution Explorer you need to enable it in Tools > Options > Environment > Documents > Show miscellaneous files in Solution Explorer

  See more about miscellaneous files at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/miscellaneous-files
- It depends what your tooling (addin, macro) wants to do.
- You can use [`EnvDTE.Constants.vsProjectKindMisc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.constants.vsprojectkindmisc?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) to identify miscellaneous files projects.

Comment: It's been so long, I have even forgotten about this question! But thanks, next time I'm writing a VS addin which maps the included projects, I'll be smarter!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps after some refactoring,you have modified the name of the project under TFS and Rename the project using the Solution Explorer (i.e. right click the project and click rename)
which does not match this project name on source Control Explorer. in this way you will see "Miscellaneous Files" in the Solution Explorer that are not associated with TFS,The Miscellaneous Files folder represents the files as links.this folder is not part of a solution, when you open a solution. Here's what worked for me:

1. Rename the project using the Solution Explorer (i.e. right click the
   project and click rename).(*you have done it before)
2. Rename the project folder in Source Control Explorer.
3. Open your solution's .sln file in a text editor, and fix the file
   path. (Replace any references to "OldPrjName" with
   "NewPrjName").
4. Reload your solution in Visual Studio.
5. Find and replace all the old namespaces with the new project name.

   Done. Check in changes.

thanks [daniel-congrove](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1937348/daniel-congrove)