# Visual Studio 2013 - Miscellaneous Files

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

Related question: [Visual Studio 2013 - project shows up as "Miscellaneous Files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259639/visual-studio-2013-project-shows-up-as-miscellaneous-files)

I have a really strange issue where when I debug my project a certain class is appearing as a 'Miscellaneous File' and is actually appearing from another branch of the same project.

I have cleaned the solution, checked the csproj files for references.  I can't find anything in google about this and found only one related question in SOF which doesn't have any answers.

Any ideas? courses of action?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was very specific to my project.  But I will try and explain what happened anyway.  The issue was that my website needs to be able to run in a sub folder (Staging) for this to work javascript needs to understand what the root of the site is (i.e. Domain.com/Staging instead of Domain.com)

Locally on my machine I tested against this 'Staging' folder by mapping in the web project IIS Express settings.

The problem started happening when the setting telling javascript that the root was 'Staging' when I was actually running against the root.

Javascript correctly - but mistakenly - then posted to the Staging folder. Which was mapped to the old branch.  hence the issue.  IIS ran against my old solution instead of the branch I was actually expecting.

I doubt that will help you if you have a simular issue.  But there you go.