# why vs2015 show on my android projct files "miscellaneous file"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

All my .cs files and resources in my project shown as "miscellaneous file" after updating Xamarin to new version. I try recreating solution, reinstalling Xamarin and nothing happen. This is the visual studio error code "IDE0006" which it shown to me.

Comment: Can you post your version information in a gist: https://gist.github.com `Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio > Copy Info [button]`

Comment: Which is your xamarin version now? Have you tried to update to the latest stable version?

Comment: Related: [Visual Studio - project shows up as “Miscellaneous Files”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24259639/1364007)

Answer (score 2):

I did not find the root of this issue but this solution worked for me:

1. Compile your project, resolving any compilation errors.
2. Right-click on the project in Solution Explorer and select 'Unload project'.
3. Once the project unloads right click on the project in Solution Explorer and select Reload Project.

Comment: Worked for me on VS 2017 , for me it seems to happen when working with git , adding new file station 1 , and then syncing on station 2 , the new files are marked as "miscellaneous "