# Visual Studio 2013 - project shows up as “Miscellaneous Files” when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a project set up of web api and wcf service. I need to debug wcf service  by sending request through web api. When i debug, wcf service class is showing in webapi project and project shows as 'Miscellaneous files'. Due to that am not able to debug the service.

[image]

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467486/3073551)? Also reloading the solution sometimes works

Comment: unloading and reloading is not worked for me. reloading the solution works sometime but not all the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity Scripts edited in Visual studio don't provide autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597501/unity-scripts-edited-in-visual-studio-dont-provide-autocomplete)