# I get an error in C# "The type or namespace name does not exist in namespace"

Tags: c#, error-handling, namespaces

I get an error in C# "The type or namespace name does not exist in namespace". I checked everywhere but it didn't solve my problem here is the main program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using BlockChainMySelf;
using Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting;

namespace BlockChainMySelf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;

            BlockChainMySelf.BlockChain StepCoin = new BlockChain();
            StepCoin.CreateTransaction(new Transaction("Henry", "MaHesh", 10));
            StepCoin.CreateTransaction(new Transaction("lkjsdf", "MaADLKHesh", 15));
            StepCoin.CreateTransaction(new Transaction("Henry", "MaHesh", 20));
            StepCoin.CreateTransaction(new Transaction("Henry", "MaHesh", 60));
            StepCoin.ProcessPendingTransactions("Bill");
```

And here is the class that I want to call

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using BlockChainMySelf;
using Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting;

namespace BlockChainMySelf
{
    public class BlockChain
    {
        IList<Transaction> PendingTransactions = new List<Transaction>();
        public IList<Block> Chain { set; get; }
        public int Difficulty { set; get; } = 2;
```

Here are the Screendhots
[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEIzh.png)

[Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY0Ue.png)

[answerquestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNEnQ.png)

[answerquestion2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AknI.png)

Comment: is `BalckChain` class in diffrent project ?! yes !

Comment: You are missing closing brackets. Is this your entire code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio - project shows up as "Miscellaneous Files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259639/visual-studio-project-shows-up-as-miscellaneous-files)

Comment: The BlockChain class is in same project and the code is not fully represented if it would change something i cane put the full code

Comment: ... your `BlockChain.cs` is in `Miscellaneous Files`, and go on according this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467486/6797509)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second screenshot in [an earlier edit of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54502712/2) clearly shows the `BlockChain` class as being 'Miscellaneous Files' in Visual Studio:

[image: second screenshot]

The [MSDN page for the Miscellaneous Files Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/miscellaneous-files-project?view=vs-2017) says (emphasis mine):

> When a user opens project items, the IDE assigns to the Miscellaneous Files project **any items that are not members of any projects in a solution**.

Presumably you were in the middle of trying to fix the issue, so you put `static` in - but that won't work because then you can't create an instance of a `BlockChain`.

Your question is a duplicate of [Visual Studio - project shows up as “Miscellaneous Files”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24259639/1364007).

The/a solution is to right-click on the bad file in Solution Explorer, remove it from the project, then re-add it, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467486/1364007).

Comment: I've edited the answer. Your question is a duplicate of the one I linked to.

Comment: I dont have the option exclude

Comment: Right-click the bad file, i.e. `BlockChain.cs`.

Comment: I updated the question and you can see my screenshot in theanswerquestion2

Comment: Something is very weird in your screenshot. A .csproj file has no business being visible in Solution Explorer. How did you make this project?

Comment: Like everyone Flie>New>Project

Comment: To be honest, as you have just two files in it, I'd create a new project and start again (take care not to delete the files you've worked on). Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: I solved the problem. The solution was this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259639/visual-studio-project-shows-up-as-miscellaneous-files

Comment: Int that case, would you mind accepting the duplicate question suggestion that I made?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue... however, I had two classes under the same namespace but in different projects. All I had to do to fix this was to add a reference to the project directly.