# Namespace path broken after changing Resources.resx properties

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a runtime `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException` on my VB.Net VSTO. I read this was likely due to wrong settings in my resources file. So I went into the properties and made sure `Build Action` was set to `Embedded Resource`(and it was).

Just below, I saw `Copy to Output Directory`was set to `Do not copy`. I thought it would not hurt if I just changed it to `Copy always` and gave it a try to compile.

It did not fix anything, but now `Build Action` has changed to `Content`, and I have dozens of `BC30456` errors:

> 'Resource' is not a member of 'WordAddIn.My'

When I go to the error, I end up in a UserControl designer, and the line with an error shows: `Me.Button_Foo.Image = Global.WordAddIn.My.Resources.Resources.Resource_Bar`

I did set my resources file settings back to what they were (`Embedded Resource`, and `Do not copy`), but the errors remain..

**Note**: the namespace of Resources.Designer is `My.Resources`, and the `Resources` class and its members are `Friend`. However intellisense does not let me access the namespace from any of the objects where I have the build errors. I have tried changing the "Custom Tool Namespace" for other names but It does not appear from anywhere in the project. (the custom tool does update the Resources.Designer.vb file, and I would say it does it properly)

---

#### UPDATE

Resources.Designer.vb is not included in the project, but shows in the "Miscellanous Files". Same symptom as this post: [Visual Studio - project shows up as "Miscellaneous Files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259639/visual-studio-project-shows-up-as-miscellaneous-files)

I did (1) exclude the `Resources.resx` (cannot work on `Resources.Designer.vb` alone) from the project, (2) clean the solution, (3) restart Visual Studio, (4) clean the solution (zust'in'kase), (5) an then re-included it, the problem now is that `Resources.Designer.vb`is included in the project, but does not sit as "embeded" within the `Resources.resx`, so I am afraid I might have broken it?

Answer (score 0):

The fix with Visual Studio 2017 was the following:

1. Note the Custom Tool namespace:  in solution explorer, right click the `Resources.resx` file  -> 'Properties' and memorize the value for the 'Custom Tool Namespace' field. (needed for step 6)
2. Remove the `Resources.resx` and the `Resources.Designer.vb` files from project: in solution explorer, for each file, right click  -> "Exclude from project"
3. Clean / Rebuild solution
4. Restart Visual Studio
5. Re-include the `Resources.resx` file , but **not** the `Resources.Designer.vb`: in solution explorer, make sure you have the [Show All Files] button enabled (near [Refresh]); the resources file should appear with a greyed folder/file symbol next to it; right click -> "Include in project" (or alternatively, right click on the 'My Project' node and choose 'Add' /  'Existing item..'
6. In solution explorer, right click on `Resources.resx` -> 'Properties': make sure 'Custom Tool' value is "PublicVbMyResourcesResXFileCodeGenerator"; and that 'Custom Tool Namespace' corresponds to the value it had before you removed the file from project (see step 1.).
7. In solution explorer, right click on `Resources.resx` -> 'Run Custom Tool'
8. A new designer file should be generated automatically.