# Miscellaneous files in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#

I am kind of new to all of this and I've been wanting to code for a long time now. I have been held back by this visual studio issue where it says I have miscellaneous files every time I open a project, and it won't go away. This issue is doing so that i can't run or debug code with C#, for some reason it can run others such as C++

I have tried multiple thing such as:

[Visual Studio - project shows up as "Miscellaneous Files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259639/visual-studio-project-shows-up-as-miscellaneous-files)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/miscellaneous-files?view=vs-2022

I am not sure if I can't fix it because I don't understand, or if it's just something else i have to try.

[image: In the image the red arrow shows where it says the miscellaneous files, and green arrow point at the run code/debug run code.]

Image of the solution explorer (one of you asked for it)
[image: Image of the solution explorer]

From comments:
I normally just open up visual studio and then I either make a project or open an already existing project. I've always had miscellaneous, files no matter how i open it. All the projects i open is miscellaneous files. Honestly I have no idea if you kan make them yourself, I usually just open visual studio then click "new project" and choose "c# console app" after that project name next i choose framework .NET 6 (long term support) with top level statement off.

I use Visual Studio 2022

Comment: do you have a project-file (.csproj), that includes that source-code-file (.cs)? You can't just "run a cs-file", you need a **project** that uses these and bundles them to a (runnable) assembly (e.g. a dll-file).

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of Solution Explorer showing the loaded solution making sure that your Program.cs is visible in the list?

Comment: Can you create a new project and run it? Please describe the precise steps you perform to create a new project.

Comment: Shing a screenshot that includes the solution explorer will help

Comment: Did you try and open a .cs file in VS, or did you open the .sln file (or maybe a .csproj)? When you create a new project, a .sln file should be created also. Open *that* in VS. A "solution" is a collection of projects, which contain files

Answer (score 0):

Miscellaneous files are those that you have opened directly, usually by double clicking in file explorer, but they are not related to the current project, if you have opened a project at all.

Visual Studio tries to actively recover files that you were editing in a previous session but did not save the changes, that might be why the files are there when you open Visual Studio.

Out of interest, are you opening Visual Studio first and then selecting a project or solution? Or are you opening Visual Studio directly first?

You need to save or close these miscellaneous files before VS will allow you compile and debug, that is because VS attempts to save all open files before continuing the build.

---

Sounds very much like your C# environment is not configured correctly. Go back to the Visual Studio Installer and make sure that the **.NET Desktop Development** workload is selected:

[image]

Comment: I normally just open up visual studio and then I either make a project or open an already existing project. I've always had miscellaneous, files no matter how i open it.

All the projects i open is miscellaneous files. Honestly I have no idea if you kan make them yourself, I usually just open visual studio then click "new project" and choose "c# console app" after that project name next i choose framework .NET 6 (long term support) with top level statement off.

Comment: What edition of VS are you using?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2022

Comment: Which edition: Community, Professional, Enterprise?